# What is the intended usage of FDetachmentTransformRules in Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal

There seems to be little to no documentation on this part of Unreal functionality and I was wondering whether anyone here had any examples to share with the community or information regarding potential usages/applications for this.

[FDetachmentTransformRules Unreal Documentation page.](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/FDetachmentTransformRules/index.html)

Comment: StackExchange is generally much better at answering "I have this problem, how do I solve it?" than it is at answering "I have this solution, what problems does it solve?" - Are you considering using FDetachmentTransformRules in your project to support some feature? If so, try telling us about the feature in your game that you want to support, and we can show you how to implement it, whether it involves FDetachmentTransformRules or not. It shouldn't really matter that other people might or might not use it for - only what you need it for in your own game.

Comment: That's a fair point. I figured I might get a better answer on here than somewhere else, as below. Should I have asked this on a forum somewhere?

Comment: I assume it was you that placed the downvote on this. This is a question that I believe benefits the community. If you feel the answer below is not sufficient to help the community, I would urge you to remove the downvote, or I can simply delete this question if you remove the downvote.

I'm trying to not have my stack overflow account banned for downvotes.

Comment: That assumption is not correct. I generally comment to recommend directions for edits, and save downvotes for situations where the post has more serious problems. Honestly though, one downvote is not anything to worry about. They happen — I've gotten a fair few in my time too. This one downvote is not a significant risk for sanction, and this isn't StackOverflow, so your account is reasonably safe. It's normal to get a few as you get the hang of the site, and they're easily counter-balanced by making quality posts that other folks want to upvote, even if the downvoter never changes their mind.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for the assumption! Yeah I had a really bad experience with StackOverflow ahaha! Thank you for the constant good advice as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components in Unreal have transformation information that is relative to their parent component. When you [attach a component](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/AttachToComponent/index.html) to a new parent, or [detach one](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/DetachFromComponent/index.html) from its current parent, Unreal will update the transformation stored in the component.

The attachment and detachment transform rules let you specify how that update occurs. You can ask Unreal to keep the relative transform as-is or update the transform so that the world space transform of the component is preserved.